# Sorted sets vs hash in Redis?

Tags: redis

I have the following information that I need to store in Redis:

```
url => {title, author, email}
```

Each of URL has `title`, `author`, `email`

So, I shall ensure that information are not dubplicated in store.

I think to use `Sorted sets` like as:

```
ZADD links_urls url "title"
ZADD links_author url "author"
ZADD links_email url "email"
```

What do you think about this? Am I wrong?

Comment: what do you mean, not duplicated? And why do you want do use sorted sets?

Comment: I mean, that I can not add the same value to sorted set, it is the main reason. But the second I should be bind these sorted sets, that to get related data from each by score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to use a sorted set. You are using `url` as a score.  However, scores must be numeric (they define the sort order).

If I understand your constraint correctly, each `url` is unique. If that is the case, I would use a hash to store everything.

I would use the url as a key, and then concatenate or JSON-encode the fields together, like this:

```
HSET links <url> '<title>::<author>::<email>'
```

This ensures constant time lookup and amortized constant time insertion.